# Is there a way to set default groups inside a EXT JS's GroupingView?

Tags: javascript, extjs, aem

I have a `CQ.Ext.grid.GridPanel` that uses a `CQ.Ext.grid.GroupingView` to group records of a `CQ.Ext.data.GroupingStore`.

I manage to successfully group rows inside the view using the `groupRenderer` property, but I would like to have a set of groups always available, even if no record belongs to that group or even if the Store is empty. Do you know if this is posible?